# How to transform XML (XML Document) using JavaScript or XSLT

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

My source XML is something like this:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <dog>OK</dog>
        <cat>KO</cat>
        <sheep/>
        <snake>OK</snake>
    </element>
    <element>
        <cat>OK</cat>
        <horse/>
    </element>
    <element>
        <sheep>KO</sheep>
        <snake>OK</snake>
        <horse>OK</horse>
        <bird>KO</bird>
    </element>
</root>
```

It needs to be converted into this format:

```
<root>
    <list>
        <element>
            <animals>
                <name>dog</name>
                <value>OK</value>
            </animals>
            <animals>
                <name>cat</name>
                <value>KO</value>
            </animals>
            <animals>
                <name>sheep</name>
                <value/>
            </animals>
            <animals>
                <name>snake</name>
                <value>OK</value>
            </animals>
        </element>
        <element>
            <animals>
                <name>cat</name>
                <value>OK</value>
            </animals>
            <animals>
                <name>horse</name>
                <value/>
            </animals>
        </element>
        <element>
            <animals>
                <name>sheep</name>
                <value>KO</value>
            </animals>
            <animals>
                <name>snake</name>
                <value>OK</value>
            </animals>
            <animals>
                <name>horse</name>
                <value>OK</value>
            </animals>
            <animals>
                <name>bird</name>
                <value>KO</value>
            </animals>
        </element>
    </list>
</root>
```

Basically, I need to get the element names and their values in the source XML and map them to the  and  elements in the target XML.

Any tips on how to achieve this in JavaScript or XSLT is really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show the code you have so far and explain where you are stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here a simple JavaScript solution.**

You can format the result [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html)

```js
function createXmlDoc(string) {
var doc;
if (window.DOMParser) {
 parser = new DOMParser();
 doc = parser.parseFromString(string, "application/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
 doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
 doc.async = "false";
 doc.loadXML(string);
}
return doc;
}
 
var parser, xmlDoc;
var text = "<root><element><dog>OK</dog><cat>KO</cat><sheep/><snake>"
 + "OK</snake></element><element><cat>OK</cat><horse/></element><element><"
 + "sheep>KO</sheep><snake>OK</snake><horse>OK</horse><bird>KO</bird></ele"
 + "ment></root>";
 
xmlDoc = createXmlDoc(text);

var oxd = createXmlDoc('<root><list></list></root>'); 
var txt;

var elements = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;

elements.forEach(function (el, idx) {
 
var nel = oxd.createElement(el.nodeName);
oxd.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(nel);

el.childNodes.forEach(function (e, idx) {

 var animals = oxd.createElement("animals");
 var nodeName = oxd.createElement("name");
 var nodeValue = oxd.createElement("value");

 nodeName.appendChild(oxd.createTextNode(e.nodeName));
 var val = oxd.createTextNode(e.childNodes.length > 0 ? e.childNodes[0].nodeValue : "");
 nodeValue.appendChild(val); 
  
 animals.appendChild(nodeName);
 animals.appendChild(nodeValue);

 nel.appendChild(animals);    
});   
});

txt = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(oxd);
console.log(txt);
```

**Result:**

```
<root>
   <list>
      <element>
         <animals>
            <name>dog</name>
            <value>OK</value>
         </animals>
         <animals>
            <name>cat</name>
            <value>KO</value>
         </animals>
         <animals>
            <name>sheep</name>
            <value />
         </animals>
         <animals>
            <name>snake</name>
            <value>OK</value>
         </animals>
      </element>
      <element>
         <animals>
            <name>cat</name>
            <value>OK</value>
         </animals>
         <animals>
            <name>horse</name>
            <value />
         </animals>
      </element>
      <element>
         <animals>
            <name>sheep</name>
            <value>KO</value>
         </animals>
         <animals>
            <name>snake</name>
            <value>OK</value>
         </animals>
         <animals>
            <name>horse</name>
            <value>OK</value>
         </animals>
         <animals>
            <name>bird</name>
            <value>KO</value>
         </animals>
      </element>
   </list>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got using XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <list>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </list>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="element">
        <element>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <animals>
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                    </name>
                    <value>
                        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                    </value>
                </animals>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you inlcude the whole solution as a code snippet, that would be nice. Thanks.